# grid-template-area : auto grid sizing on conditional event

Tags: css, css-grid, autosizing

I'm encountering a problem auto sizing a grid element if some condition arises.

Consider the following grid:

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "1  2   2   2"
    "3  4   4   4"
    "5  6   7   8";
```

What I need is to 6 to take up the space of 7 and 8 if 7 and 8 are not present in the html which might happen.

That would make the grid template look like this one:

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "1  2   2   2"
    "3  4   4   4"
    "5  6   6   6";
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="details-etherlns-incident">
   <div class="1">Text</div>
   <div class="2">Text</div>
                    
   <div class="3">Text</div>
   <div class="4">Text</div>
   
   <div class="5">Text</div>
   <div class="6">Text</div>
                    
<?php if (someCondition): ?>

   <div class="7">Text</div>
   <div class="8">Text</div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: you can apply such logic to the grid items not the grid container. We need to see your html code structure for this

Comment: I added a sample of my html, thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below. You only need one rule applied to 3 selectors. The item 6 will be considered only if it's the last one

```css
.details-etherlns-incident {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.details-etherlns-incident :nth-child(2),
.details-etherlns-incident :nth-child(4),
.details-etherlns-incident :nth-child(6):last-child {
   grid-column: 2/span 3;
}

 

.details-etherlns-incident > * {
  border:1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="details-etherlns-incident">
   <div class="1">Text 1</div>
   <div class="2">Text 2</div>
                    
   <div class="3">Text 3</div>
   <div class="4">Text 4</div>
   
   <div class="5">Text 5</div>
   <div class="6">Text 6</div>
                    
   <div class="7">Text 7</div>
   <div class="8">Text 8</div>

</div>

<div class="details-etherlns-incident">
   <div class="1">Text 1</div>
   <div class="2">Text 2</div>
                    
   <div class="3">Text 3</div>
   <div class="4">Text 4</div>
   
   <div class="5">Text 5</div>
   <div class="6">Text 6</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. What would happen if I needed the same condition say on this grid layout : grid-template-areas: 
    "1  2   2   2"
    "5  6   7   8" 
    "3  4   4   4"; that is the last row would now be in the middle ?